# ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails with Oauth2RestTemplate, setting username and password

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am currently at the point where I configure my Oauth2RestTemplate with my controller. The said controller would recieve the user's username and password to be set in the ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails however, I am not seeing how this is set. This application is for an Oauth2 client setup.

```
 //An extention of ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails that adds a property 'token'.

 <bean id="cPassword" class="com.cointraders.site.overrides.TokenOauthResourceDetails">
     <property name="grantType" value="c_password"></property>
     <property name="clientAuthenticationScheme" value="header"></property>
     <property name="clientId" value="cointraders"></property>
     <property name="clientSecret" value="p@ssw0rd"></property>
     <property name="accessTokenUri" value="${oauth.accessTokenUri}"></property>
 </bean>  

 //My controller using the 'cPassword' bean above

 <bean id="loginController" class="com.cointraders.site.controllers.LoginController">
    <property name="checkCredentialRest">
        <oauth:rest-template resource="cPassword">
        </oauth:rest-template>
    </property>
 </bean>

//My Controller

@RequestMapping(value="/login")
public class LoginController {

     private OAuth2RestTemplate checkCredentialRest;

     private OAuth2RestTemplate loginCredentialRest;

     public void setCheckCredentialRest(OAuth2RestTemplate checkCredentialRest) {
             this.checkCredentialRest = checkCredentialRest;
     }

     public void setLoginCredentialRest(OAuth2RestTemplate loginCredentialRest) {
             this.loginCredentialRest = loginCredentialRest;
     }

     @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
     @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.OK)
     public void verifyCredential(@RequestBody LoginCredential creds)
     {

     }
 }
```

As can see, from my 'verifyCredential' I am passing the credentials mapped to a datamapper LoginCredential. This class has properties for 'username', 'password' and 'token' for the user. At this point, I was thiking it would be easy to pass the LoginCredential's object properties to the OAuth2RestTemplate loginCredentialRest but, that is not the case.

Also I have configured the ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails with the access token endpoint (accessTokenUri) and basically wired this object into the Oauth2RestTemplate. How would I use it to make a request to the access token endpoint supplying the "username", "password" and "token" for an Access Token?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure I understand the need for it or your use case in any detail, but in Spring OAuth 2.0.4 you can add the user credentials to the `AccessTokenRequest` before calling the `AccessTokenProvider` (i.e. not using `OAuth2RestTemplate` until you have an access token to give it).